# Automate LT-SPICE?

Tags: ltspice, python, automation

I'm running a lot of simulations in LT-Spice, and I need someway to run them all either sequentially or at the same time.

I was going to use Python, but I'm not entirely clear on how I would get past the GUI and open the netlists I have and be able to run them all and collect the data I need.

Is there some easier way to run a large ammount of simulations at once?

As an example I have about 25 models that I need to run with various transistor model files that I reference in a library folder that I swap out for every iteration. 
I have 4 transistor nominal models that each have different speeds that need to be tested.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.